# How to select distinct values from one column in table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing a restaurant menu app in Android. My app has one database table which has the following columns:

- id (primary key)
- category
- item name

The category column shows the category of item such as veg, non veg, snacks etc. It has duplicate values and I want to select only distinct values from this column. I have tried the following but it is not working if anyone can provide a solution:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM todo";

Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
}

return cursor;
```

Comment: i am not getting any sqlite errors, but app stops running, debuger shows error source not found. Curently i am not using any logging in app

Comment: You should use logcat to debug your application. It will give us more information about your problem..

Answer (score 12):

You can also use this specific query-Method of the SQLiteDatabase class that takes a boolean value to determine whether you want distinct values or not:

public Cursor query (**boolean distinct**, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)

[Link to Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

This way you don't have to use rawQuery at all.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT category as _id, category FROM todo"
```

This worked for me in the same situation.

Comment: Could you explain what this means? Why do you need to replace "FROM todo" with "as _id, category FROM todo"?

Comment: This answer should really include more details than it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i make distinct, also to get categories

```
// Get Categories
public Cursor getCategories() {

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_ITEM_CAT + " as " + KEY_ITEM_ID
            + ", " + KEY_ITEM_CAT + " FROM " + ITEMS_TABLE_NAME, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same question, and I found something which is direct to the solution in the most simplest way! Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879436/4072073