# select distinct value in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to run the following raw query in android, it seems not work

```
String query ="SELECT DISTINCT category FROM event";
Cursor  cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
if (cursor != null) {
     cursor.moveToFirst();
}
return cursor;
```

so I decide to use the query() method in android which are something like

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(EVENT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_CAT}, null, null,null,null, null)
```

Can anyone show me how to select the distinct category for using query() instead of rawquery please, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should avoid use of `rawQuery` whenever possible... always prefer the built in `SQLiteDatabase` query methods over `rawQuery`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, 
                     String[] columns, String selection, 
                     String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, 
                     String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

Here first argument specifies whether to use distinct or not.

Comment: so how to select distinct category, that's for  select the whole row right?

Comment: Pass only `category` in `columns[]`, as you just need that column in result as shown in your row query, and you will get distinct categories.

Answer (score 64):

But you MUST remember to send argument in `GROUPBY` (`NOT NULL` send).

You must give column name for `distinct`.

Example:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, YOUR_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME_1 ,COLUMN_NAME_2, COLUMN_NAME_3 }, null, null, COLUMN_NAME_2, null, null, null);
```

true - distinct TRUE

`COLUMN_NAME_2` - name column what you have be DISTINCT.

That's works for me fine.

Comment: EPIC WIN ! You sir, ARE AWESOME ! I've been looking for hours for this problem, thanks a lot for your input. You really made my day.

Comment: Thanks a ton! this is what I was looking for. specially to deal with contentprovider along with cursorloader. I did a small hack and this worked!

Comment: Yes, have to say thank you too. Was searching and trying many suggestions, only yours worked for me. Thank you for sharing. Keep it up.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways, as already green ticked. But if somebody is looking to get it via raw query then here you go:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM event";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select column1 column2...  Distinct column3 from "+Table_name, null);
```

`column3` is a distinct column