# Inserting record in sqlite results in duplicate record

Tags: android, sqlite

When i insert one record then duplicate entry is generated that means total two same entries are display. My query for select statement is following:
How to make distinct record???

```
Cursor cur = db.query("timer", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: check: [select distinct value in android sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11219399/379693)

Answer (score 0):

To make a distinct selection define a boolean Variable like :

```
private boolean Distinct = true;
```

then change your query to :

```
c = db.query(Distinct,DATABASE_TABLE,cols,null,null, null, null,
                    null,null);
```

Comment: this is the way that u can make a distinc selection if you have another problem with your code plz provide your java code,maybe we can help you