# How to make... SQLite select DISTINCT -> query(true, ...)

Tags: android, sqlite

My query is:

```
String _query = "select DISTINCT Y.CATE_CODE4 CATE_CODE, Y.CATE_NAME4 CATE_NAME,
                 0 IS_PRESET from G_MASTER X INNER JOIN CATEGORY_VIEW Y ON X.CATE_4 = Y.CATE_CODE4
                 where X.IS_SALE = 1 AND Y.IS_LOCKED4 = 0 AND Y.CATE_NAME2 not in ('XXXX')";
```

How does Android SQLite make `db.query()`?

Comment: You want to know how to query in Android Sqlite?

Comment: It seems ready for a `db.rawQuery()`...

Comment: my query have..., DISTINCT keyword...T.T db.rawQuery() not working ..

Comment: ... so what? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_distinct_keyword.htm **Who told you** that `rawQuery()` can't do something that `query()` can?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219361/select-distinct-value-in-android-sqlite                android sqlite ...

Comment: FWIW, all `query()` does is that it constructs an SQL string and feeds it to `rawQuery()`. Don't believe everything you read online.

Comment: By the way, I had dinner with Santa Claus, yesterday evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should read [SQLiteDatabase reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

You could use a `rawQuery()`, here's an example of it :

```
rawQuery - db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT Y.CATE_CODE4 CATE_CODE, Y.CATE_NAME4 CATE_NAME,
             0 IS_PRESETG_MASTER X INNER JOIN CATEGORY_VIEW Y ON X.CATE_4 = Y.CATE_CODE4 from table where X.IS_SALE = 1 AND Y.IS_LOCKED4 = 0 AND Y.CATE_NAME2 not in ('XXXX')"",new String[]{"data"});
```

*It's just an example, you have to adapt your code to this.*

Comment: String _query = "select DISTINCT Y.CATE_CODE4 CATE_CODE, Y.CATE_NAME4 CATE_NAME, 0 IS_PRESET from G_MASTER X INNER JOIN CATEGORY_VIEW Y ON X.CATE_4 = Y.CATE_CODE4 where X.IS_SALE = 1 AND Y.IS_LOCKED4 = 0 AND Y.CATE_NAME2 not in ('XXXX')";
  

Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(_query, null);

it doesn't woking...T.T

Comment: I told you it was just an example how to do it... not the solution.